# Registry Tweak for Instant Effect on Windows

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, windows-registry

I saw it before on a computer at school but sadly I failed to find out how to achieve it.

I want to make Windows Explorer read the Registry changes I made instantly without needing to re-log in **or** killing the **explorer.exe** process then start it again. I saw it at a unit at school before, one of the teacher was asking us how to show the hidden Folder Options in Windows Explorer via the Registry. I tweaked the registry and was about to log out when I noticed that the changes I made already took effect instantly and that Folder Options was already shown even before Windows Explorer was restarted.

Now I have a problem wherein I want to have that same setup on my own computer. As I said, I failed to investigate what tweak was on the unit at school that made it read the tweaks instantly.

Comment: this is the default behaviour isn't it?  I notice registry changes immediately upon making the edit using regedit, I don't have to log out and in again.  Unless something is being cached...

Comment: Most registry changes take effect immediately, some do require a reboot, log off or explorer restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy. All you need to do is to create a .reg file, double click it and the change is effective immediately.

Copy the following to a text editor and save the file as `ShowHiddenFiles.reg`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\SHOWALL]
"CheckedValue"=dword:00000001
```

A `CheckedValue`of 2 hides hidden files, a checked value of 1 shows them.

Comment: Umm I don't think that's related to my question though...

Comment: "want to make Windows Explorer read the Registry changes I made instantly without needing to re-log" - use a `reg` file. "hidden Folder Options" and " - "I want to have that same setup" use the provided settings I gave you. If I have misunderstood your question, please make me understand it.

Comment: Oh I got what you were trying to explina, but I didn't use a reg file before. I edited it directly at the Registry Edtior. There must be some kind of tweak on the registry to make Windows Explorer act that way besides using Reg files....

Comment: make Windows Explorer act **WHAT** way? show hidden files? Besides using the .reg file you can also start `regedit.exe` and navigate to the path you see above (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software...), double click "CheckedValue" and change the Value data to 1 -essentially that is the same the .reg file does, just manually.